# Why is the recipes not showing in the application after I fill in the state with the response in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, axios, react-lifecycle

The ingredients data is not showing on the page after I call the setState method to the this.state.ingredients

I have tried to change the different parameters in my code such as res.data.recipes, etc

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './RecipeForm';
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'f562842f0ff6b2d4fd24b9601aeb5e1b';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ingredients: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=f562842f0ff6b2d4fd24b9601aeb5e1b&q=shredded%20chicken'
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          ingredients: res.data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const recipeList = this.state.ingredients.length ? (
      this.state.ingredients.map(ingredient => {
        return (
          <div key={ingredient.recipe_id}>
            <p>{ingredient}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <div>There are no ingredients here</div>
    );
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: 50 }}>
        <Form />
        <div>{recipeList}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

There is no output to the page where I map out the data

Here is the console.log I have

````
config: {url: "https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=bfb76b78b11e7308cc3c027865a508dd&q=shredded%20chicken", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data:
count: 30
recipes: Array(30)
0: {publisher: "Closet Cooking", f2f_url: "http://food2fork.com/view/35171", title: "Buffalo Chicken Grilled Cheese Sandwich", source_url: "http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/08/buffalo-chicken-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html", recipe_id: "35171", …}
1: {publisher: "All Recipes", f2f_url: "http://food2fork.com/view/29159", title: "Slow Cooker Chicken Tortilla Soup", source_url: "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Slow-Cooker-Chicken-Tortilla-Soup/Detail.aspx", recipe_id: "29159", …}
2: {publisher: "My Baking Addiction", f2f_url: "http://food2fork.com/view/e7fdb2", title: "Mac and Cheese with Roasted Chicken, Goat Cheese, and Rosemary", source_url: "http://www.mybakingaddiction.com/mac-and-cheese-roasted-chicken-and-goat-cheese/", recipe_id: "e7fdb2", …}```
````

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already did that. It was actually what I had first before I started to change the code around

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data from the request?

Comment: probably because you hit your API limit, otherwise, without being able to see the response data structure sounds like you are not storing the data to state properly which is making `this.state.ingredients.length` always `false` because obj.length is undefined or falsy

Comment: Yes, I am getting data as the response is coming in my console.log and showing the data

Comment: what is the data

Comment: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=f562842f0ff6b2d4fd24b9601aeb5e1b&q=shredded%20chicken", method: "get", 

Here is the data

Comment: whats in the `data` key?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add `res.data` from your `console.log`?

Comment: `console.log(this.state.ingredients);` at the top of your `render()` function and paste the output from your console when you edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far guys. @technogeek1995 I have logged this.state.ingredients under the render method. It is showing the info in the state, however, not rendering to the interface.

Comment: This may seem like a dumb suggestion, but it seems like it should be `res.data.recipes` instead of just `res.data` based on your `console.log`. It seems like `data` consists of both count and recipes? so if you want to iterate over recipes, it should be `res.data.recipes`?

Comment: Wow, actually that was it! Thanks so much! @technogeek1995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `componentDidMount`, you need to set `ingredients` to `res.data.receipes` instead of `res.data`. `res.data` is only the server's response payload. If you want to access some of the data inside, it you have to index into the response object further. However, this isn't always good because sometimes (if an error occurs) `recipes` may not be there. In that case, you should have a `catch` block (like in the [Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage)).

```
this.setState({
  ingredients: res.data.receipes
});
```